# x86 LODSB STOSB LOOP explanation

Tags: loops, assembly, x86

I ran across these instructions:

```
...
...

get:
lodsb  
xor eax,ebx 
stosb  
loop get 
push esp 
pop esi 
int3
```

I see that this loads a byte does an xor and stores the byte in a loop and it will do this until ECX = 0. My question is how does the program know to continue onto the `push esp` instruction? Is this just implied by the loop block syntax?

Comment: _" it will do this until ECX = 0"_ yes that means it will go on to the `push esp` once `ecx` becomes zero. What else do you think could happen?

Comment: Every instruction, after it is fetched and decoded, will implicitly increment `eip` by it's size. The jump-and-similar instructions may then later during execution phase tamper with that value further, like redirecting the `eip` to point back to `get:` address, but otherwise the `eip` will point to instruction after the current one, and that's the point where the execution will continue.

Comment: Heh. Try Harder! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the `loop` instruction might be a bit misleading.  You might be tempted to believe that all it does is to jump to the given label, but think about it: if it was just a jump, then what would the difference be between `loop` and all the other `jmp` instructions?

The truth of the matter is that `loop` is not just a jump.  It does the following two things:

1. It decrements the ecx register.
2. if the result of the decrement was not zero, it jumps to the given label.

So, as you can see, it is perfectly suited for loops, and that's why it is called `loop`.